# DOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation in drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal

I was trying to install drupal website that I got from a client so as to debug their website behaviour. but when I try to install the website in local I encountered this error that made me unable to continue debugging. this error happened after I had restored the database through mysql commandline. 
here is the screenshot.

[image]

```html
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'userdrupal'@'localhost' for table 'semaphore': SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of C:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\lock.inc).
```

and also below that another error that says.

```js
Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 DELETE command denied to user &#039;userdrupal&#039;@&#039;localhost&#039; for table &#039;semaphore&#039;: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 20189744505893d71c6d55d1.25943049 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of C:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\lock.inc).
```

so what should I do then from here? any help would be appreciated though.

Comment: It looks like a permission issue. I don't know where dupral store the credentials for the database access but I would check somewhere around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB account data is stored in /sites/default/settings.php (D6 & D7) but to me it looks like that DB account you used there don't have permissions to delete data or something like that.

Check what permissions permissions have that user you set in your settings file. Does it have full CRUD or something is missing.

Comment: yes you're right. I just need to change to the original database already setup inside the drupal. making new database shows up that error.